# How to convert uint256 timestamp to a hh:mm:ss timestamp and int256 to a float number?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

Total coding newb here. Sorry if my questions look dumb.

I am interested in a couple of things.
First is converting a uint256 timestamp to a timestamp that I can check on the clock such as hh:mm:ss.
For example, the following:

startTimestamp   uint256 :  1678871792
lockTimestamp   uint256 :  1678872092
closeTimestamp   uint256 :  1678872399

How can these be made into something that I can look up in time?
As they are in the form above, I have no idea when that was.

These numbers are from a pancakeswap contract.
Exact details you can see here:
`https://bscscan.com/address/0x18b2a687610328590bc8f2e5fedde3b582a49cda#readContract`

In field "20. rounds" you can input a round number and it will give you the details of that round.
The numbers above are for round number 154535 although you can check the data for every past round.

The second thing I'm looking to do is get price data for those same contracts.
In bscscan it's displayed as int256.
For example:

lockPrice   int256 :  27554820000
closePrice   int256 :  27550780000

I have no idea how much that is in USD lol.
Pancakeswap displays these prices as float values when you check the data live on their website.

Any help with this will be greatly appreciated.

I tried googling conversion but couldn't find anything that solved my issue lol

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

When programming it's much easier to compare times when they're uint256, and not human-friendly strings such as the "hh:mm:ss" format.

So, let's say you want to know the hour of the day of a timestamp:

Let's first get the amount of seconds since the beginning of the day, and in order to do this we can use the modulo operation. Typically the modulo operator is `%`, same in Solidity.
This operator gives you the remainder of a division.

We want to get the remainder of the timestamp divided by the amount of seconds in a day: 60 * 60 * 24

So:
1678872399 % (60 * 60 * 24) = 33999

Now you can retrieve the hour:

33999 / (60*60) = **9.44416666667**

You can retrieve the minute by just multiplying by 60 the decimals after the dot, you can get those by using again the modulo operator:

9.44416666667 % 1 = 0.44416666667

0.44416666667 * 60 = **26.65**

Repeat the same operation to get the seconds:

26.65 % 1 = 0.65
0.65 * 60 = **39**

Now you know that this timestamp represents 9:26:39 (in 24h format)

You can verify here by yourself: https://www.epochconverter.com/

### TL;DR

You can get the time of the day out of a timestamp by applying some simple math. Solidity unfortunately doesn't support float numbers, so (I guess) the result of division will always be a int.

```
uint256 timestamp = 1678872399;
uint32 secondsInDay = timestamp % (60 * 60 * 24); // 33999
uint16 secondsInHour = secondsInDay%(60*60) // 1599
uint8 secondsInMinute = secondsInHour%(60) // 39
uint8 hour = secondsInDay/(60*60)
uint8 minute = secondsInMinute = secondsInDay/60
uint8 second = secondsInMinute

// Let's say you want to check if an operation happened after 9AM
if(hour >= 9) {
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your timestamp query, this solves the problem

```
contract TimestampTest {
   function getTimestampInHMS() public view returns (string memory) {
      uint256 timestamp = block.timestamp;
      uint256 _hours = (timestamp / 3600) % 24;
      uint256 _minutes = (timestamp / 60) % 60;
      uint256 _seconds = timestamp % 60;

      return string(abi.encodePacked(
         _hours < 10 ? "0" : "", toString(_hours), ":",
         _minutes < 10 ? "0" : "", toString(_minutes), ":",
         _seconds < 10 ? "0" : "", toString(_seconds)
      ));
   }

   function toString(uint256 val) internal pure returns (string memory) {
      if (val == 0)
         return "0";
      uint256 digits;
      uint256 tmp = val;
      while (tmp != 0) {
         digits++;
         tmp /= 10;
      }
      bytes memory newBuffer = new bytes(digits);
      while (val != 0) {
         digits -= 1;
         newBuffer[digits] = bytes1(uint8(48 + val % 10));
         val = val / 10;
      }
      return string(newBuffer);
   }
}
```

For your second query, here is a JS code with a possible approach.

```js
const convertPriceToUSD = (tokenPriceUSD, amount = 27554820000) => {
    const amountBNB = amount / 10 ** 18;
    const amountUSD = amountBNB * tokenPriceUSD;
    return amountUSD;
};
```

I recommend asking other queries in a different post.

Answer (score -1):

hi guys I can help you  for your problem and you can in javascript convert example like this  :

```js
const timestampConvert = (unix) => {
  var a = new Date(unix * 1000);
  var months = [
    "Jan",
    "Feb",
    "Mar",
    "Apr",
    "May",
    "Jun",
    "Jul",
    "Aug",
    "Sep",
    "Oct",
    "Nov",
    "Dec",
  ];
  var year = a.getFullYear();
  var month = months[a.getMonth()];
  var date = a.getDate();
  var hour = a.getHours();
  var min = a.getMinutes();
  var sec = a.getSeconds();
  var time =
    date + " " + month + " " + year + " " + hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec;
  return time;
};
```

Comment: I don't see how this can be of any help at all

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).